# How to change language at the whole app and remember it?

Tags: android, localization

I would like to change app language and then remember it for usage at all activities. How I can do it without custom library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my first self-response, but I'd like to share my own way of changing language with everybody who will need it. You can see simple steps below:

1. You have to create all string resources at languages which you will need: en, ru or smth like that.
2. Then you have to add smth for language changing at your app xml, like button or checkboxes.
3. Add two methods at your activity where you will change your lang:

   ```
   private void changeLang(String lang) {
       if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
           return;
       Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
       Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
       android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
       config.locale = myLocale;
       this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
       saveLocale(lang);
   }

   private void saveLocale(String lang) {
       String langPref = "Language";
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
       editor.putString(langPref, lang).apply();
   }
   ```

at the `changeLang` method you have to use identifiers of locals. 
And finally you have to check your sharedPreferences at each activity before `setContentView(...)`:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String lang = sp.getString("Language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I agree that my method can be too simple or it is created wrongly, but it helps me and I decided to share it with you. Maybe smb will use it at his or her projects. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is duplicate. Stack overflow is full of info how to do this.

Comment: @VygintasB, so I have to delete my answer?